# creating new binary columns using range of numbers in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, split, binary

I am using pandas library in python for the following:

i currently have a dataset that looks like this :

```
ID       START      END
x         450       600
y         100       500
.          .         .
```

Here start and end represent footmarks, ie a vessel was parked here from point x to y.

What i want to do is create binary columns 1, 2 3... till the max value in 'END' and have it show a 1 if that column number is within the range of 'START' to 'END'

what i want to accomplish here is finding the total number of times all the footmarks have been used. Right now my approach is to have the binary columns and sum them up to get the total count.

I am also open to better methods of solving my problem.

edit_1:

What i want -

```
ID       START      END    1   2   3  ...... 450 ..... 500 .... 600   601  
x         450       600    0   0   0          1         1        1     0
y         100       500    0   0   0          1         1        0     0
.          .         .
```

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: nothing so far, i looked up the get_dummies function but cant seem to figure out how to do that for a range of numbers.

Comment: @AasheetKumar, can you post your desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU will edit that in right now

Comment: @AasheetKumar, could you also explain why do you need such an unusual (not very efficient) structure?

Comment: So the dataset above is shows the footmarks of vessels ie a ship was at the dock and its location was from x footmark ( the number is x feet from left most side of dock) to y footmark. Now taking into account multiple vessels coming to the dock, i want to count the number of times the vessel have been at a particular footmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to loop through values 1 to `max('END')` and produce True/False values based on range `START` to `END`. I think you want something like:

```
for i in range(1,df['END'].max()+1):
    df[i] = ((i >= df['START']) & (i <= df['END'])).astype(int)
```

However, if you only want to figure out the number of steps where all rows "overlap", you can just do:

```
max((df['END'].min() - df['START'].max()), 0)
```

Since the vessels will only overlap when everything is `>= 'START'` but `<= 'END'`

Comment: the first part worked for me, thank you. The second code is not exactly what i am looking for, i have just added a comment to the question, maybe that helps explain my needs better. Thank you again!